# http.Request.Clone() is not deep clone?

Tags: http, go

i want get a Request , and use ParseForm to check some data , then send the same one to proxy , buy if i do that , we have a problem

error log like this

> 2020/05/26 15:34:47 http: proxy error: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: http: ContentLength=32 with Body length 0

so I finally figured it out , ParseForm () well close Request .body

and this is work proxy  code

```
    url, _ := url.Parse(config.GetGameHost())

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
    r.URL.Host = url.Host
    r.URL.Scheme = url.Scheme
    r.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-Host", r.Header.Get("Host"))
    r.Host = url.Host
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
```

so , i think i need clone the deep clone request too get my data and send origin request too proxy 
i edit my code too this

```
nr := r.Clone(r.Context())
nr.ParseForm()

url, _ := url.Parse(config.GetGameHost())

proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)

r.URL.Host = url.Host
r.URL.Scheme = url.Scheme
r.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-Host", r.Header.Get("Host"))
r.Host = url.Host

proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
```

and the error log show again

> 2020/05/26 15:49:29 http: proxy error: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: http: ContentLength=32 with Body length 0

is the Clone() are not deep clone or i do wrong?

------------ this work------------

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
url, _ := url.Parse(config.GetGameHost())

r2 := r.Clone(r.Context())

r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))
r2.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))

r.ParseForm()

proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r2)
```

Comment: It makes a deep copy, but the copy does _not_ read the body twice. It just copies the io.Reader to the new request, and whichever request is read first will get the body, unless you make an effort to duplicate the body.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http.Request.Body can only be read once, a new body needs to be copied.

```golang
body,err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
r2 := r.Clone(r.Context())
// clone body
r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))
r2.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))

// parse r1, proxy r2
r.ParseForm()
proxy.ServerHTTP(w, r2)
```

The body object defaults to net.Conn multi-layer encapsulation. Each time it uses the io.Reader interface to read 4kb, saving memory usage, it is generally used while reading from the network.

Therefore, the body can only be read from the network once. If you want the body object to be read repeatedly, you should read it all, save it, and use it.

Comment: The first line should be `body,err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)`?

Comment: @codewarrior You can use ioutil, but it is recommended to replace it with the `io.ReadAll` function